# It's possible know who is calling my QML property?

Tags: properties, qml, sender

I don't know who is setting a width property in a Rectangle.
I'ts possible to know who is calling the width property?
For example:

```
    Rectangle
{
    onWidthChanged: console.log ("who is calling me: ", sender())
}
```

Comment: Property changing event fired by item itself. You have to clarify your question. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article before.

Comment: Properties are not called. They are neither methods nor functions nor other kind of callables.

Answer (score 0):

Find where the signal is emitted in C++ (git grep on a clone of Qt's source), set a breakpoint there, and then debug the application. In your case it's probably here:

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitem.cpp#n3794